# How to find all words with a certain occurrence frequency, excluding some words

Tags: python, dictionary, frequency

I want to find all words with a frequency of occurrence `>= 30`, excluding the words `"the"`, `"and"`, `"to"` and `"a"`.

I tried the following code:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open ('clienti_daune100.json') as f:
    data=json.load(f)

word_list=[]

for rec in data:   
      word_list=word_list + rec['Dauna'].lower().split()
print(word_list[:100], '...', len(word_list), 'Total words.' )

dict = {}

for word in word_list:
    if word not in dict:
        dict[word] = 1
    else:
        dict[word] += 1

w_freq = []

for key, value in dict.items():
    w_freq.append((value, key))   

w_freq.sort(reverse=True)
pprint(w_freq[:100])
```

I know I have to put a condition in the dictionary, but I can not figure out which one.

Comment: Define a set of `excluded_words` and then put `if value >= 30 and key not in excluded_words:` in the last loop so you only append the words you want to `w_freq`.

Comment: Gecko has already given a good answer, but I'll just add that you should be careful calling a variable dict, as it is an inbuilt method which will be overshadowed.

Answer (score 2):

Filter your data first and then you can use `itertools.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

# I think your data is just a list. So image you have
data = ['the', 'box', 'and', 'the','cat', 'are', 'in', 'that', 'other', 'box']
# List the words we don't like
bad_words = ['the','to', 'a', 'and']
# Filter these words out
words = [word for word in data if word not in bad_words]
# Get the counts
counter = Counter(words)
```

Result (which you can just convert to a regular dict if needed)

```
Counter({'box': 2, 'cat': 1, 'are': 1, 'in': 1, 'that': 1, 'other': 1})
```

Finally you do your filter for the number of words (which in this case is empty)

```
{word: count for word,count in counter.items() if count>=30}
```